# Is it possible to make Angular one-time binding the default?

Tags: angularjs

I know you can make a one-time binding by adding `::` to the expression. I wonder if there is a way to make that the default and just add some identifier to expressions that you need to update?

Thank you! :)

Comment: interesting question...not sure how practical it would be though but I never deal with a completely static workflow

Comment: I was optimizing a website and found me writing ```::```all the time. The pages where mostly just loading JSON data from a server and rendering lists and the data would never change once it was loaded. It's so easy to introduce performance issues especially with ng-repeat. If you have a list of 100 items and 10 expressions for every item you have 1000 watchers visiting!

Comment: Its very simple but may not work for any third party libraries based on angular that you use

Comment: @Harsh simple but how?

Comment: @charlietfl After looking at the angularjs code. In $ParseProvider the return $parse has a condition if (exp.charAt(0) === ':' && exp.charAt(1) === ':') {oneTime = true;. So we can make the default value of the variable  as oneTime = true n inside this as false. This will work.

Comment: I can't believe it's really just that easy but it seems to do the trick! Thank you!